# A reliable HTTP library for .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, http, timeout

.Net's implementation of HTTP is ... problematic. Beyond some issues in compliance with HTTP/1.0, what's bugging me right now is that `HttpWebResponse.GetResponse()` with ReadTimeout **and** Timeout set to 5000 blocks for about 20 seconds before failing (the problem is it should fail after 5 seconds, but it actually takes 20 seconds).

I need a library with better protocol conformance and timeout control. Know any?

Comment: +1 I'm also interested. What version of .NET are you on? with that ReadTimeout issue?

Comment: 2.0.

What's your second question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8e554674-8e4e-4e29-bb77-b9c2b287ed50), what could be hanging is possibly the DNS resolution, which may take up to 15 seconds.

Solution - do the DNS resolving on your own (Dns.BeginGetHostByName).

Answer (score 0):

[Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/HttpDotNet.asp) has a HTTP Component. I've never used it, but I have been impressed with some of their other components.

Answer (score 0):

See the HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse() method.  Not exactly what you asked for, it's been a few days since you've had any other responses and it deserves a mention.